# How to calculate the total price in fast food ordering program via external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new to the forum and very new to javascript. To get straight to the point, the problem is it won't calculate when one item is not selected/ordered. It works fine when all of them are selected, but when one is missing, it just show NaN. I tried to change the code; from bit by bit to the whole entire thing, but i just cant seem to get it. At one point, when i click the compute button, it doesnt show anything at all. i've been working on this for a whole week now, researching and restarting again and again. hopefully you guys could share some tips, insight or explanation on how to do this. i'm really new at this.

The javascript is external.

Here's what i got on my html &external javascript (im sorry if my code is a mess, im not really sure how to approach the problem well):

```js
function compute() {

  var a1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("regburg").value);
  var b1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("chburg").value);
  var c1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("spclburg").value);
  var d1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("regfrs").value);
  var e1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lrgfrs").value);
  var f1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("xlfrs").value);
  var g1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("regdr").value);
  var h1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("meddr").value);
  var i1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lrgdr").value);



  if (a1 < 0 || b1 < 0 || c1 < 0 || d1 < 0 || e1 < 0 || f1 < 0 || g1 < 0 || h1 < 0 || i1 < 0) {

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ERROR";

  } else {
    var a2 = 0;
    var b2 = 0;
    var c2 = 0;
    var d2 = 0;
    var e2 = 0;
    var f2 = 0;
    var g2 = 0;
    var h2 = 0;
    var i2 = 0;

    var a2 = a1 * 27;
    var b2 = b1 * 45;
    var c2 = c1 * 70;
    var d2 = d1 * 25;
    var e2 = e1 * 37;
    var f2 = f1 * 45;
    var g2 = g1 * 20;
    var h2 = h1 * 30;
    var i2 = i1 * 35;

    var x = a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 + e2 + f2 + g2 + h2 + i2
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Total =" + x;

  }
}
}

function change() {
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("pay").value);

  var total = y - x;

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> Ordering Program </h1>
  <form>
    <p><br> Please input the quantity of your order.
      <br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;B U R G E R S </p>

    Regular Burger: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="regburg"> &emsp;
    <br><br> Cheeseburger: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="chburg"> &emsp;
    <br><br> Special Burger: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="spclburg">
    <br><br><br>

    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;F R I E S </p>

    &emsp;Regular Fries: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="regfrs"> &emsp;
    <br><br> &emsp;Large Fries: &emsp;&emsp;
    <input type="text" id="lrgfrs"> &emsp;
    <br><br> Extra Large Fries: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="xlfrs">
    <br><br><br>

    <p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;SOFTDRINKS </p>

    Regular Drink: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="regdr"> &emsp;
    <br><br> Medium Drink: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="meddr"> &emsp;
    <br><br> Large Drink: &emsp;
    <input type="text" id="lrgdr">
    <br><br><br>
  </form>

  <P id="output"> </P>
  <script src="cmpt.js">
  </script>



  <input type="submit" onclick="compute();return false;" value="Compute">
  <br><br>

  <form>
    Payment:
    <input type="text" id="pay">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="change();return false;" value="Enter">



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When `parseInt` cannot convert the input to a number (for example because it is an empty string), it will return NaN.

You can write your own replacement function that will return -1 instead, so that your check for `< 0` on all the variables works.

```
function parseIntOrMinus1(input)
{
    var result = parseInt(input);
    if(Number.isNaN(result))
    {
        result = -1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now simply use `parseIntOrMinus1` instead of `parseInt` in your code.

If you want to treat an empty input field as "0", simply use this version instead:

```
function parseIntOrMinus1(input)
{
    var result;

    if(input == '')
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        result = parseInt(input);

        if(Number.isNaN(result))
        {
            result = -1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: so i put this in the external javascript right? but im not exactly sure how or where in the code i should put this. well at least to call it out so that i can use it. sorry, im really a beginner to this.

Comment: @cookienicky this is a normal function like the change and calculate functions that you already have. Just put it in the same place.

Comment: oh okay. but how do i use it exactly? i mean, do i have to call it out for it to work or is it automatic? sorry, im really new at this.